# How to force clients to use server's time when copying to Samba server?

Tags: samba

I have a Samba 4.2 server running on a FreeBSD 11 machine. Everything is looking fine, but Windows client will preserve the timestamp instead of using the server's time for new files (I haven't tried with other OS yet). I just want new files to have the server's time, just like transferring with SFTP or FTPS.

Comment: I guess you can't. See https://serverfault.com/questions/54155/how-to-use-noatime-with-smbfs

Answer (score 0):

In your smb.conf `[global]` insert `time server = Yes`, now you can use on windows `NET TIME \\SERVER /SET /YES`

The above command can be placed in your logon script if you are in domain.